# Understand a derivation

Tags: logic

I am learning formal logic through the book [An Exposition of Symbolic Logic; in chapter 1, section 10](https://logiclx.humnet.ucla.edu/Logic/Documents/CORE/LogicText%20Chap%201%20Aug%202013.pdf), I am asked to derivate the following argument:

> (P→Q) → S
>
> S → T
>
> ~T → Q
>
> ∴ T

I couldn't work out the solution, so I saw the answer the book tells:

> 1. <strike>Show</strike> T
> 2. ~T ass id
> 3. Q 2 pr3 mp
> 4. <strike>Show</strike> P→Q
> 5. ```
>       Q 3 r cd
>    ```
> 6. S 4 pr1 mp
> 7. T 6 pr2 mp 2 id

When I saw the derivation on line 4 to 5, I said to myself "this is nonsense!". So I ask: is it wrong? If it is right, could you explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to spend too much time deciphering this book's idiosyncratic and obscure system of abbreviations.  But I gather that the idea is:

1. We have already shown $Q$ in step 3.
2. We can hypothesize  $P$ in step 5 and then claim that $P\to Q$ because $Q$ has already been shown.

This is sometimes called the rule of [reiteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem#Virtual_rules_of_inference).  (I suppose this is why the author chose the notation `r`.)  Symbolically, we can write it as $$A \to (B \to A)$$  If we already know $A$, we can conclude that $B$ implies $A$, for any $B$.  In your derivation, because we already know $Q$, we can conclude $P\to Q$.

This is indeed counterintuitive.  It's one of the notorious [paradoxes of material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication).  The confusion arises because the formal logical meaning of $A\to B$ is so different from the conventional notion of "if… then…”.

In formal logic, $A\to B$ is a  very weak claim.  It does not say that $A$ causes $B$, or that $A$ and $B$ are related in any way.  All it says is that whenever $A$ is true, $B$ is also true.

But if we interpret $\to$  in this way, $A\to (B\to A)$ is always true.  It says is that whenever $A$ is true, $B\to A$ is also true.  And this is correct!   Because if $A$ is true then, whenever $B$ is true, $A$ is also true.

---

Perhaps a more straightforward way to prove the theorem would be:  Assume $\sim T$.  From premise 2 conclude $\sim S$ by modus tollens.  From $\sim S$ and premise 1, conclude $\sim(P \to Q)$ by modus tollens.  $\sim (P\to Q)$ means $P\land \sim Q$ by definition, so extract $\sim Q$. From premise 3, conclude $Q$ by modus ponens, a contradiction, and the original assumption $\sim T$ is false.

But I make no guarantees that all these steps are valid in this author's unpleasant logical system.  My advice would be to pick up a secondary text that explains how to do proofs  via analytic tableaux, and learn logic from that.   Once you understand it, writing the proofs in a more natural way, and then translating them into your book's weird formalism, will probably be easier than trying to construct the proofs  directly in the weird formalism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the derivation notation of this book uncommon?

Comment: I've never seen anything quite like it before.

Comment: but the notation in the first yellow box and the notation in (";" is a line break) "1. Show W; 2. A pr; 3. A => B pr; 4. B 2 3 mp; W 4 pr3 mp dd" is common?

Comment: It is an old style, and a little obscure, but not entirely illegible. Current best practice is to place what is being shown *after* its subproof.